# Is the "r" in "universe" syllabic?

Tags: english, phonology, phonetics, syllabic-consonants

Good morning,

Is the "r" is the word "Universe" syllabic?

I learned how to identify the syllabic letters, but still find it hard to do so.

Comment: 1 if your Scottish, I think, 2 if you're Amercan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Universe" certainly might be pronounced with a syllabic r. Whether it actually is depends on your accent. Many American English speakers can have "syllabic r" in any position in a word, unlike other syllabic consonants, which must occur in unstressed syllables.

However, because syllabic r in American English behaves similarly in terms of phonology to a vowel + consonant sequence or just a vowel, it may be transcribed as something like ər, ɜr, əɹ, ɜɹ, or ɚ, ɝ. (A transcription like er would not be considered correct!)

But a transcription like [ɹ̩] is not incorrect. See the following handout from the website of [Kevin Russell](https://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/%7Ekrussll/) at the University of Manitoba: [[ɹ̩] -- Syllabic [ɹ]](https://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/%7Ekrussll/phonetics/transcription/english-symbols/syllabic-r.html)

> There is a major split between English dialects where the pronunciation of the word *bird* contains an [ɹ] sound (e.g., western Canada, central and western U.S., northern England) and those where it does not (e.g., southern England, Australian, parts of the north-east and southern U.S.). In dialects which do not use an r sound in *bird,* the vowel between the [b] and the [d] is traditionally transcribed as [ə] or [ɜ].
>
> Dialects which do use an [ɹ] sound in *bird* tend to use nothing but. In normal western Canadian or American speech, the period of time between the [b] and the [d] will be entirely occupied by an [ɹ] sound, and there will be no other vowel in the word. The [ɹ] is acting as the core of the syllable in [bɹd], a privilege which is usually reserved for vowels. A vertical line diacritic is used to mark those occasions where [ɹ] has a special vowel-like role in a syllable. The usual transcription *bird* is therefore [bɹ̩d]. (Sometimes you'll run across the symbols [ə˞] or [ɜ˞] or even the sequence [əɹ] used instead of [ɹ̩].)

The phonological analysis of syllabic consonants is somewhat complicated, but I think a fairly common analysis is to treat them all as sequences of schwa + a consonant phoneme. So you may be more likely to encounter something like /junɪvərs/ or /junəvərs/<sup>1</sup> in the context of phonemic transcription.

(Actually, a number of American dictionaries seem to feel like there is something special about the last syllable of *universe* relative to the last syllable of a word like *Oliver’s,* in that they mark the last syllable of *universe* with a stress marker, or transcribe it with the symbol ɜ. This can sometimes indicate a lack of vowel reduction; however, I myself cannot hear any difference in quality between the supposedly unreduced or minor-stressed /ɜr/ or /ˌər/ and reduced, fully unstressed /ər/. However, I guess the absence of “flapping”/“tapping” of the /t/ in the final syllable of words like *dramaturge, thaumaturge, taciturn, Astroturf* could be considered to imply that either the presence of minor stress or the presence of vowel reduction is phonologically contrastive for [ɹ̩] in American English. Thus, if we mark stress, and use the symbol ˌ to indicate minor (i.e. tertiary) stress as well as secondary (major) stress, it may be correct to transcribe the pronunciation of *universe* in American English as  /ˈjunɪˌvərs/ or /ˈjunəˌvərs/<sup>1</sup>.)

---

1. Many American English speakers have the "weak vowel merger" and so do not feel like they have a phonemic contrast between /ɪ/ and /ə/ in fully unstressed syllables. The neutralization of /ɪ/ and /ə/ is typically transcribed as /ə/, although word-final /ə/ in American English (e.g. in *comma* or *Rosa*) tends to be realized with a more open quality (often near the realization of the STRUT vowel, which may be somewhere around [ɜ] or [ɐ]) than the neutralization of /ɪ/ and /ə/ that occurs in non-word-final positions.